# Downgrade ubuntu version

Tags: downgrade

recently upgrade my ubuntu from 18 to 22 from focal fossa to jammy . And notice that my pgAdmin4 and PostgreSQL are not working. So I want to come back to a previous version. How can I do it?

Comment: You can't downgrade. You will have to reinstall. See https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: Since there's no direct way to upgrade 18.04 to 22.04, can you please elaborate how did you upgrade? Did you edit sources.list and ran `sudo apt upgrade`?

Comment: Or do what you really should do: fix your progress problem.

Comment: Your options are limited at this point because Ubuntu 22.04 has not been released yet and questions about 22.04 are currently being closed as off-topic.  Once 22.04 is released you can start a new question and ask about and provide details about your actual problem. This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), since the answer to your question is *"You cannot downgrade"* - but this doesn't solve your problem.  I suggest that you reinstall a supported release. Or, if the problems are tolerable for a week or two, wait for 22.04 to be officially released, and then install that

Comment: See also [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/q/34430) - The short answer is **"No"**

Comment: @Kulfy Strangely, Focal Fossa is 20.04?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: The title (18 to 22) doesn't match the body of the question (focal[20.04] to jammy[22.04]). So it's unclear what you did. The tested, supported upgrade path from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 is scheduled to open in July 2022 after MUCH more testing and preparation -- you are much too early. There is no tested, supported upgrade path from 18.04 to 22.04 except via 20.04. Advice: Reinstall your previous release of Ubuntu and restore your data and customizations from your backups.

Comment: @mchid Yes, 20.04 is focal fossa. However op mentioned Ubuntu 18 which I assumed to be 18.04. I don't know where the typo is. whether in release number or release name.